# Node.js cannot read UDP streams from interface other than 'lo'

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, port, firewall

I have been using the Node.js UDP sockets to receive LIDAR data sent over ethernet, to then send it to the client. I had been using tcpreplay to capture the UDP data and then resend it for testing purposes. This was the command I used to replay the data (using Ubuntu 20.04).

```
sudo tcpreplay -i lo <pcap file>
```

Now, I obviously want this data to come through live, i.e. without using tcpreplay and by just plugging in the LIDAR sensor. The problem is that this obviously uses a different interface, namely "eth1" instead of "lo". Node.js somehow cannot read any UDP messages however.

I have tried numerous different things, like adding the specific IP of the interface to the server.bind() (in the code, see below), or specifically  opening the port on my firewall, etc.

To open the firewall for port 2368, I used:

```
sudo ufw allow 2368
```

Any idea what the issue might be? Thanks in advance.

Here is the Node.js code:

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

// UDP/datagram sockets experimentation
// https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_udp_datagram_sockets

const dgram = require("dgram");
const server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  server.close();
});

server.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(msg.buffer);
});

server.on("listening", () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind(2368);
// Prints: server listening 0.0.0.0:2368

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("velodyne");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: NB 'UDP stream' is a contradiction in terms. UDP is a datagram protocol. No stream.

Comment: Okay, it is just because the lidar sensor does not stop stending UDP datagrams, but it is indeed irrelevant for my question, as I just do not receive any packets. Any idea why this would word on 'lo' interface, and not on 'eth1'?